# Nextjs app dynamic route reload all page, not only update url, use shallow

Tags: next.js, navigation, transition

I have `pages` in NextJS and by `useRouter()` I can detect dyanmical changes url and make changes on page without refresh content (I nee do transitions on current page).

pages/[page]/index.js:

```
import Link from "next/link";
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
import s from "./style.module.css";

export default function Page() {
  const router = useRouter()
  const {page} = router.query
  return (
    <>
      <div className={page == "page1" ? s.login : s.register}>{page}</div>
      <br />
      <Link href={"/page1"}>
        page1
      </Link>
      <br />
      <Link href={"/page2"}>
        page2
      </Link>
    </>
  );
}
```

style.module.css:

```
.register,
.login {
  transition: background linear 0.5s;
}
.register {
  background: red;
}
.login {
  background: green;
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/pages-shallow-hj33m4

But I have problem with do similar in `app`. On click link, page is refreshed and I haven't transition. `usePathname from 'next/navigation'` also not working, page is reload. Add `shallow` to Link also not resolve problem with reload page.

```
import Link from "next/link";
import s from "./style.module.css";

export default function Page({ params: { page } }) {
  return (
    <>
      <div className={page == "page1" ? s.login : s.register}>{page}</div>
      <br />
      <Link shallow href={"/page1"}>
        page1
      </Link>
      <br />
      <Link shallow href={"/page2"}>
        page2
      </Link>
    </>
  );
}
```

In above example I know that `Page({ params: { page } })` change state and refresh component, but `usePathname from 'next/navigation'` do that same.

```
"use client";

import Link from "next/link";
import s from "./style.module.css";
import { usePathname } from "next/navigation";

export default function Page() {
  const pathname = usePathname();
  return (
    <>
      <div className={pathname == "/page1" ? s.login : s.register}>
        {pathname}
      </div>
      <br />
      <Link shallow href={"/page1"}>
        page1
      </Link>
      <br />
      <Link shallow href={"/page2"}>
        page2
      </Link>
    </>
  );
}
```

How to do similar from `pages` in `app` NextJS?

https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/app-shallow-y8h7nt